# Rails query through multiple models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It's been 2 days by now that I'm struggling to write query. So, I'm trying to query within these 3 related models:

```
class Company...
  has_many :programs
end

class Program...
  belongs_to :company
  has_many   :transactions
end

class Transaction...
  belongs_to :program
end
```

As output, I need a list of the amount of all **Transactions** each **Company** made and on what date.

Comment: could you please explain better what you need as output?

Comment: Hey @Fallenhero, I've updated the question. Do I made myself clear now or you still don't get it?

Comment: Well @Fallenhero, I was trying with `Transaction.joins(program: :company)` and group it by the company ID. But I couldn't get nowhere with this approach. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be something like this.

`Company.includes(:programs => :transactions).map do |company|
  {:company_name => company.name, 
   :transactions => company.programs.map{|program| program.transactions.map{|t| {:amount => t.amount, :date => t.created_at.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")}}.flatten
}
end`

You could change the format of the date by referring to strftime method of Time class from here - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime.